# can't read from SerialPort

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a message via serial port (plugged in a RS-422 to my computer by USB)

The problem is that i have 2 cables of this type.

One is a USB straight to 422 and the other one is a usb-RS-232 cable with a RS-232 to RS-422 adapter.

I've installed all the drivers.
I write the line: `m_Pod.read(response, 0, 1000);` where `m_Pod` is the SerialPort object and `response` in the byte[] to save the message read.

This line is in an event that if data is received, so I read the message.

The first connector works fine, and I read the message when the event occurs.
The second connector, however, doesn't work. The event doesn't occur.
If I try to read the message manually, I get a random number (63), instead of the long message I'm supposed to.

This is a picture of the second adapter:
http://oi50.tinypic.com/34nh4kz.jpg

On the right is the USB to RS-232 and on the left is the RS-232 to RS-422.

Comment: If the first connector works fine, I suspect that your problem is with the second connector and not the C#.

Comment: the one thing is that there's another program (written in c++), and the second one works there.

sorry for keeping this information out.

Comment: Do you have the source code of that c++ program ? You could analyze it and check the differences with your C# application...

Comment: 63 is a magic number, it is the ascii code for '?'.  Which is the character that's generated by the default SerialPort.Encoding when it converts a byte that's not a valid ascii value.  What that has to do with the signaling type is unguessable.  Maybe a bad baudrate.

Comment: Hy Hans, I checked all those com port properties and they are the same as in the program that works

Why would the serial port send me '??' ?

There is another thing, that if I do read a second time, an exception - timeout appears.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried playing with Handshake property?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.handshake.aspx
Depending on what signals your adapter is using/providing you might need to select from software/hardware handshaking.

Comment: i tried reading about handshake, it's used to send messages when i request it right?
i don't know if it would help me, because the serial port doesn't sent me messages, only "??"

Comment: Handshake is used for flow control. Some devices might not be capable of full-duplex communication, or might not be constantly pooling to read data, but rather waiting for some "signal" (interrupt) that initiates the transfer.
That way these "handshake" part is critical for setting up a communication. Some devices (and/or cables) might be supporting only specific handshake types. 
This would also explain why both adapters work in C# while the second one works just in C++.

Comment: You can also try using http://www.rohitab.com/ to monitor API calls of C++ application. That way you can easily tell how it is accessing serial port.